# jquery autocomplete for a textbox should not allow data other than the autocomplete list

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

jquery autocomplete for a textbox should not allow data other than the autocomplete list.,but the problem is i need to allow only data from the list autocomplete list but not any other data, even if the user enter any another data we i need to show a message that please select from the autocomplete list.

The link show below is also allowing any data other than the autocomplete suggestions:

```
  $("#field").autocomplete({
    source: countries_starting_with_A,
    minLength: 1,
    select: function(event, ui) {
        // feed hidden id field
        $("#field_id").val(ui.item.id);
        // update number of returned rows
        $('#results_count').html('');
    },
    open: function(event, ui) {
        // update number of returned rows
        var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
        $('#results_count').html('(#' + len + ')');
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        // update number of returned rows
        $('#results_count').html('');
    },
    // mustMatch implementation
    change: function (event, ui) {
        if (ui.item === null) {
            $(this).val('');
            $('#field_id').val('');
        }
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/32Bck/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do this. Here is one suggestion:

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/32Bck/560/

**HTML**

```
<div class="ui-widget" style="position: relative;">
  <input type="text" placeholder="type something ..." id="suggest" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
  padding: 30px;
}

input.ui-state-alert {
  border: 1px inset #F00;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var makeSelect = false;
$(document).ready(function() {
  function requiredValid(target) {
    target = $(target);
    // Return Focus
    target.focus();
    // Add alert class
    target.addClass("ui-state-alert");
    $("<div>", {
      class: "required-alert-text",
      style: "color: #F00; font-size: 10px; display: inline-block; position: absolute;"
    }).html("Must select from list.").insertAfter(target).position({
      my: "bottom",
      at: "top+5",
      of: target
    });
  }
  $("#suggest").autocomplete({
    delay: 100,
    source: function(request, response) {
      // Suggest URL
      var suggestURL = "http://suggestqueries.google.com/complete/search?client=chrome&q=" + request.term;

      // JSONP Request
      $.ajax({
          method: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp',
          jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
          url: suggestURL
        })
        .success(function(data) {
          response(data[1]);
        });
    },
    select: function(e, ui) {
      makeSelect = true;
    },
    close: function(e, ui) {
      if (makeSelect) {
        makeSelect = false;
        $(".ui-state-alert").removeClass("ui-state-alert");
        $(".required-alert-text").remove();
      } else {
        requiredValid(this);
      }
    }
  });
  $(".ui-state-alert").on("blur", function() {
    $(this).focus();
  })
});
```

This will not cover all cases. Basically, we want to know if the user made a selection from the list. I created `makeSelect` and assigned it as `false`. We assume upfront that the user has not done this.

When the user selects a list option, `select` callback is triggered and updates out variable. This also triggers `close` callback as it is now closing the list. If the user has made a selection, we move one and reset for the next time. If not, we apply some techniques to alert the user and keep focus until they make a selection.